# Arduino parsing of a string using sscanf

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c

Hello I am new to Arduino and C programming.
I wanted to parse string using sscanf fuction

This is my Program

```
String hith;
int field1,field2;
float field3;
int F1=0,F2=0;
float F3=0;
int h1,h3;
float h2;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  field1=5;
  field2=6;
  field3=56.67;
  F1=field1;
  F2=field2;
  F3=field3;

  hith =hith+F1+","+F3+","+F2;
  Serial.println(hith);

sscanf(hith.c_str(),"%d,%f,%d",&h1,&h2,&h3);

Serial.println(h1);
Serial.println(h2);
Serial.println(h3);
  hith="";

  delay(1000);
}
```

I am only able to Parse Integer values but not Floating points.

Comment: `%f` is not implemented in the Arduino world.

Answer (score 1):

On 8-bit Arduinos support for %f from `printf` and `scanf` (and related functions) has been removed to save space.

Instead you should look at parsing the string into chunks with `strtok()` and use `atof()` to convert relevant chunks to floating point.